# heroku migration error using laravel and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, heroku

I was trying to deploy my project built using Laravel but when I came to apply the command

```
heroku run php artisan migrate:refresh
```

I got an error

```
In Connection.php line 742:
                                                                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to   
   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json null, `uuid` char(36) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `up   
  dated_at` t' at line 1 (SQL: create table `transactions` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `payable_type`   
   varchar(191) not null, `payable_id` bigint unsigned not null, `wallet_id` bigint unsigned not null, `type` enum('deposit', 'withd   
  raw') not null, `amount` decimal(64, 0) not null, `confirmed` tinyint(1) not null, `meta` json null, `uuid` char(36) not null, `cr   
  eated_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

I don't really know how to solve that.  appreciate your help .

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? It sounds like it may not support json columns, which was added in 5.7.8

Comment: This is a database error. Contact the person responsible for database operation and discuss the issue.

Comment: when I apply  $ mysql -V
got -> F:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.22-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)

Comment: That may not be the version that heroku is running

Comment: @aynber how can I know the Heroku version ?

Comment: Who is managing the databases on heroku for that project? You really should ask someone who is or takes responsibility there as the topic looks to be only a guessing game for you. Look for help with people who are able to help (stakeholders in your project).

Comment: It is my personal project so I want to deploy it .

Comment: Please compare with the Q&A material closed against. Additional use Heroku support resources and those of Laravel to match your system requirements, e.g. that the database is of type and version your project requires, Laravel supports and the Hosting Service Provider offers on a system to rent.

Comment: my problem is that I am using laravel-wallet which has it is own migration I do not know how to change the json to text of the package's files .